# when I select more than 4 node it give me wrong result in treeview

Tags: c#

### I want to make the tree like this:

[the tree  I  want to make](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8AUEO.png)

this the table with data:
[The table with clearifyed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5MxjI.png)
 and I tried to make this code to populate parent's and children nodes it's gives me the first node right result and the other node are wrong results .

this the code:

```
//FillTreeView with 5 parent
    public void FillTreeViewWith5(string Query1, string Query2, string Query3, string Query4,
        string Query5,string Query6,string Query7, DataSet Ds, TreeView tr, TreeNode tn1,
        TreeNode tn2, TreeNode tn3, TreeNode tn4, TreeNode tn5,TreeNode tn6,TreeNode tn7)
    {

        int z = 0;
        int r = 0;
        int res;
        //to put it as parameters
        string i1;
        string i2;
        string i3;
        string i4;
        string i5;
        string i6;
        tr.Nodes.Clear();

        SqlDataAdapter da1 = new SqlDataAdapter(Query1,con);
        da1.Fill(Ds, "d1");
        for (int i = 0; i < Ds.Tables["d1"].Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            i1 = Ds.Tables["d1"].Rows[i][0].ToString();
            string x1 = Ds.Tables["d1"].Rows[i][1].ToString();
            tn1 = new TreeNode(x1);
            SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand();
            cmd2.Connection = con;
            cmd2.CommandText = Query2;
            cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@i1", i1);
            SqlDataAdapter da2 = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd2);
            da2.Fill(Ds, "d2");
            for (int j = 0; j < Ds.Tables["d2"].Rows.Count; j++)
            {
                i2= Ds.Tables["d2"].Rows[j][0].ToString();
                string x2 = Ds.Tables["d2"].Rows[j][1].ToString();
                tn2 = new TreeNode(x2);
                tn1.Nodes.Add(tn2);
                SqlCommand cmd3 = new SqlCommand();
                cmd3.Connection = con;
                cmd3.CommandText = Query3;
                cmd3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@i2", i2);
                SqlDataAdapter da3 = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd3);
                da3.Fill(Ds, "d3");
                for (int b = 0; b < Ds.Tables["d3"].Rows.Count; b++)
                {
                    i3 = Ds.Tables["d3"].Rows[b][0].ToString();
                    string x3 = Ds.Tables["d3"].Rows[b][1].ToString();
                    tn3 = new TreeNode(x3);
                    tn2.Nodes.Add(tn3);
                    SqlCommand cmd4 = new SqlCommand();
                    cmd4.Connection = con;
                    cmd4.CommandText = Query4;
                    cmd4.Parameters.AddWithValue("@i3", i3);
                    SqlDataAdapter da4 = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd4);
                    da4.Fill(Ds, "d4");
                    for (int c = 0; c < Ds.Tables["d4"].Rows.Count; c++)
                    {
                        i4 = Ds.Tables["d4"].Rows[c][0].ToString();
                        string x4 = Ds.Tables["d4"].Rows[c][1].ToString();
                        tn4 = new TreeNode(x4);
                        tn3.Nodes.Add(tn4);
                        SqlCommand cmd5 = new SqlCommand();
                        cmd5.Connection = con;
                        cmd5.CommandText = Query5;
                        cmd5.Parameters.AddWithValue("@i4", i4);
                        SqlDataAdapter da5 = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd5);
                        da5.Fill(Ds, "d5");

                        for ( int m= 0; m <Ds.Tables["d5"].Rows.Count ; m++)
                        {

                            i5 = Ds.Tables["d5"].Rows[m][0].ToString();
                           string x5= Ds.Tables["d5"].Rows[m][1].ToString();
                           tn5 = new TreeNode(x5);
                           tn4.Nodes.Add(tn5);
                           SqlCommand cmd6 = new SqlCommand();
                           cmd6.CommandText = Query6;
                           cmd6.Connection = con;
                           cmd6.Parameters.AddWithValue( "@i5",i5);
                           SqlDataAdapter da6 = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd6);
                           da6.Fill(Ds, "d6");

                            for (int p= 0; p < Ds.Tables["d6"].Rows.Count; p++)
                            {
                                i6 = Ds.Tables["d6"].Rows[p][0].ToString();
                                string x6 = Ds.Tables["d6"].Rows[p][1].ToString();
                                tn6 = new TreeNode(x6);
                                tn5.Nodes.Add(tn6);
                                SqlCommand cmd7 = new SqlCommand();
                                cmd7.CommandText = Query7;
                                cmd7.Connection = con;
                                cmd7.Parameters.AddWithValue("@i6", i6);
                                SqlDataAdapter da7 = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd7);
                                da7.Fill(Ds, "d7");
                                res=Ds.Tables["d7"].Rows.Count;
                                for (r = z; r < res; r++)
                                {
                                    string i7 = Ds.Tables["d7"].Rows[r][0].ToString();
                                    string x7 = Ds.Tables["d7"].Rows[r][1].ToString();
                                    tn7 = new TreeNode(x7);
                                    tn6.Nodes.Add(tn7);
                                }
                                z = r;
                                res = res + res;

                            }






                        }


                    }

                }


            }


        }

        tr.Nodes.Add(tn1);
        tr.ExpandAll();

    }
```

calling the method:

```
   public void Fill(TreeView tr)
   {
       TreeNode tn1=new TreeNode();
       TreeNode tn2=new TreeNode();
       TreeNode tn3 = new TreeNode();
       TreeNode tn4 = new TreeNode();
       TreeNode tn5 = new TreeNode();
       TreeNode tn6 = new TreeNode();
       TreeNode tn7 = new TreeNode();
       DataSet ds = new DataSet();
       A.FillTreeViewWith5("select Re_id,Re_nm from RegionsTbl where Parent_id=0", "select Re_id,Re_nm from RegionsTbl where Parent_id=@i1", "select Re_id,Re_nm from RegionsTbl where Parent_id=@i2", "select Re_id,Re_nm from RegionsTbl where Parent_id=@i3", "select Re_id,Re_nm from RegionsTbl where Parent_id=@i4", "select Re_id,Re_nm from RegionsTbl where Parent_id=@i5", "select Re_id,Re_nm from RegionsTbl where Parent_id=@i6", ds, tr, tn1, tn2, tn3, tn4, tn5, tn6,tn7);


   }
```

and it gives me the first nodes right and the other not.

What is the wrong with this code ? and if there better ways it will be nice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, but this code is awful on many levels. It's hard to read it, it will be hard to maintain it, main method is way to long, not flexible (what if you need 8, 9, or 10 levels?), too many connections are opened etc.

To fix it, you just need to use recursion. That means that one block of code is executed numerous times, in loop. This way code is much simpler, there is only one query etc.

So, to explan how it is done:

First, get all the regions from table, without any filtering. Just load whole table from server into `DataTable`. Then, we will use `AddTreeNode` method recursively (one call to that method and that method calls itself numerous times).

`AddTreeNode` takes three parameters: `parentNode` (node to which other nodes is added), `table` (that is `DataTable` of all rows with regions, fetched at the beginning) and `parentId` (parent Id).

When we call `AddTreeNode` first time, we pass null (as parent, because there's no parent, `TreeView` will be used, `DataTable` and 0 as `parentId` (first level). `DataTable` is then filtered to get only rows with passed `parentId`, each of those rows is added as `TreeNode` to `parentNode` (to `TreeView` for first time). After that, `AddTreeNode` calls itself, this time passes newly created node as `parentNode`, same `DataTable` and newly created node's ID as `parentId`. `AddTreeNode` gets while there are nodes that have specified parent, no matter how many levels needed.

And now, the code:

Put this somewhere in your code, in `Form_Load` for example

```
//first, fetch data
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("your connection string");
//get all the data
string query = "select Re_id,Re_nm, parent_id from RegionsTbl";
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(query, con);
DataTable table = new DataTable();
da.Fill(table);

//call AddTreeNode method 
AddTreeNode(null, table, 0);
tr.ExpandAll();
```

`AddTreeNode` method:

```
private void AddTreeNode(TreeNode parentNode, DataTable table, int parentId)
{
    //filter rows, get all rows that have specified parent ID
    var filteredRows = table.AsEnumerable().Where(r => Convert.ToInt32(r["parent_id"]) == parentId).ToList();
    //go through all those rows
    foreach(DataRow row in filteredRows)
    {
        //make treeview
        TreeNode node = new TreeNode(row["Re_nm"].ToString());
        //add it to parent (first time that will be treeview)
        if (parentNode == null)
            tr.Nodes.Add(node);
        else
            parentNode.Nodes.Add(node);

        //now call same method second time, now with new node and parent id 151111
        AddTreeNode(node, table, Convert.ToInt32(row["Re_id"]));
        //next time, this will be called with parent id 151112 etc.
    }
}
```

To test it, i used some of your data, like this (instead of `SqlDataAdapter`)

```
DataTable table = new DataTable();

table.Columns.Add("Re_id", typeof(int));
table.Columns.Add("Re_nm", typeof(string));
table.Columns.Add("parent_id", typeof(int));

table.Rows.Add(new object[] { 151111, "region", 0 });
table.Rows.Add(new object[] { 151112, "yemen", 151111 });
table.Rows.Add(new object[] { 151113, "ibb", 151112 });
table.Rows.Add(new object[] { 151117, "saudi", 151111 });
table.Rows.Add(new object[] { 151118, "ryath", 151117 });

AddTreeNode(null, table, 0);
```

Try to go through this example and understand it. If you have additional questions, feel free to ask.

Comment: Thank you very much it help me and I try it .

Comment: @salmabdullsamad so, did you fill your treeview? Have you used code from this answer?

Comment: yes I've used it and it help me a lot thank you very much.

Comment: yes I've tried it and it worked fine thank you very much.

Comment: @salmabdullsamad mark my answer as solution if it helped you :)